# RadTabStrip appears to have no RadTab selected - Why?

Tags: asp.net, tabs, telerik, webforms, rad-controls

Does a RadTabStrip work in a MasterPage? The tabs do not appear selected when clicked.

**Steps:**

1. Create a new Web Application Project. By default it contains Home and About tabs inside a Master Page (Site.Master). The tabs are asp:MenuItem controls.
2. Comment out the asp:Menu control and drag a RadTabStrip in its place. Add two RadTabs. When you run the application each tab works as expected -- it appears to be selected when clicked.
3. Now add NavigateUrls to each RadTab pointing to the "~Default.aspx" and "~About.aspx" pages. When the application runs the tabs don't appear to be selected when clicked (although the correct page displays).

   **What's going on? How can I make this work?**

Update: Here's how I altered the default code in Site.Master...

```
<div>
    <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </telerik:RadScriptManager>
</div>

        <%--<div class="clear hideSkiplink">
            <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About"/>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
        </div>--%>

    <div>
        <telerik:RadTabStrip ID="RadTabStrip1" runat="server">
            <Tabs>
                <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Text="Root RadTab1" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx">
                </telerik:RadTab>
                <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Text="Root RadTab2" NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" >
                </telerik:RadTab>
            </Tabs>
        </telerik:RadTabStrip>
    </div>
```

**The answer...**

[Bojan Skrchevski's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351982/bojan-skrchevski) answer [led me to this](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip/selected-tab-not-highlighted.aspx). I added this code to the Master Page's Page_Load event and it works:

```
using Telerik.Web.UI;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RadTab currentTab = RadTabStrip1.FindTabByUrl(Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
            if (currentTab != null) currentTab.Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post up some of your code specifically your TabStrip

Comment: The RadTab is causing a postback...see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you also need to add `runat="server"` to the RadTab element if you want to use it like that. For example:

```
<telerik:RadTab Text="Home" NavigateUrl="Default.aspx" runat="server">
</telerik:RadTab>
```

You can also use `ContentUrl` in the corresponding `telerik:RadPageView` to navigate on the client side. Example:

```
<telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView1" runat="server" ContentUrl="Default.aspx">
```

**UPDATE(on your update):**
When you add `runat="server"` to the RadTab then it causes a postback. On postback the control is unable to determine which tab is selected even though it navigates to the specified page. Here's how it is solved in the Telerik [example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip/examples/applicationscenarios/sitenavigation/defaultcs.aspx?page=admission):

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            string urlWithSessionID = Response.ApplyAppPathModifier(Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
            RadTab tab = RadTabStrip1.FindTabByUrl(urlWithSessionID);
            if (tab != null)
            {
                tab.SelectParents();
                tab.PageView.Selected = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's it! Your answer led me to this: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip/selected-tab-not-highlighted.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I can see in your code compared to my master page is SelectedIndex="0" on the RadTabStrip and Selected="true" on one of the Rad Tabs:

```
<telerik:RadTabStrip ID="RadTabStrip1" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0">
    <Tabs>
        <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Text="Root RadTab1" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Selected="true">
        </telerik:RadTab>
        <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Text="Root RadTab2" NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" >
        </telerik:RadTab>
     </Tabs>
 </telerik:RadTabStrip>
```

Comment: With those changes only the first tab appears selected even after clicking the second tab. Odd.